# Empty data directory in Android virtual devices

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I downloaded the Android SDK and installed it at C:\AndroidSDK on Windows 8. After installing several APIs, tools and extras with the Android SDK Manager, I created two AVDs of the 4.0" WVGA, one using ARM (armeabi-v7a) and one using Intel Atom (x86). Both used API level 15. I started both from the AVD Manager but they both had black screens with "Android" in the middle. A splash screen was never displayed and when I looked at the emulators with adb shell and eclipse DDMS, the data directories were empty.

What can I do to fix this problem?

[NOTE: I had previously tried to install an apk file on an emulator but received an error that data/local/tmp was not found. I then completely uninstalled the Android SDK, deleted C:\Users\Steve\.android and did the above.]

Comment: Hi, I am very new to android programming, but I have seen long startup times sometimes. My emulator usually takes 3-5 mins to startup. Some of my friends with a slower system actually wait upto 10-15 mins or emulator to startup. I dont know if its normal behaviour but its like this in my case.

How long did u wait with the black screen?

Also as far as i know the data directries are empty when u create an emulator .. until u push something of your application creates a file.

Comment: Rahul, I waited over 30 minutes but nothing changed. In addition, I get "failed to copy" errors when I use adb install (no such file or directory) or adb push (read-only file system).

Comment: UPDATE: I entered the commands
_italic_ adb shell 
su 
mount -o rw,remount rootfs / 
chmod 777 /data _italic_
then exited adb and tried to "adb install" the .apk file. I received the message
_italic_ Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running? _italic_

Comment: I tried to edit the last post but apparently hit the magical 5 minute limit. It should read as follows: I entered the commands "adb shell," "su," "mount -o rw,remount rootfs /" and "chmod 777 /data," then exited adb and tried to "adb install" the .apk file. I received the message "Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running?"